# Problem in Android AudioStream class in new API 32

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, rtp

The AudioStream class in API 32 is having a problem with the join method, what does it do together with the AudioGroup class, I just opened a call for Google but the same ones didn't help me, someone has the same problem or I've gone through something similar, I'm not going to to first native class do google be with problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSzAl.png)

Answer (score 0):

all SIP-related classes, incl. [`AudioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioGroup) and [`AudioStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream), were deprecated in API31, so you just can't rely on these on API31+

> This class was deprecated in API level 31.
> SipManager and associated classes are no longer supported and should not be used as the basis of future VOIP apps.

edit after some inspection: built-in [`AudioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioGroup) class doesn't have `add` or `remove` methods. Inspect your `import`s

Comment: @AudioStream if "AudioStream" is deprecated from API level#31, what is the alternative?

Comment: 3rd-party app/lib or own code, Google just stopped providing SIP client